# How would I make the hour calculation between to dates and hours

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, rates

[image]

As you see in the picture I have 3 rates.

YELLOW rate
Monday - Saturday 00:00 - 06:00
Monday - Friday 18:00 - 24:00
Saturday 11:00 - 18:00

WHITE rate
Monday - Friday 06:00 - 18:00
Saturday 06:00 - 11:00

RED rate
Saturday 18:00 - 24:00
Sunday 00:00 - 24:00

How would I make the hour calculation between to dates and hours like

So if I worked

START: 8. january 10:00
END: 9. january 23:00

How can I make a javascript calculation on that?

Comment: have you tried anything?  you haven't posted any code at all to show what calculations you are trying to do.

Comment: this link should help
[how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript), and remove the 24 in the operation.

Answer (score 0):

One of the rates could be the default rate, it looks the white is suitable for this. 
Next, create data structure to define the two other rates. This data structure for yellow rate could be like this:

```
var yellow = [];
var monday = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23];
var tuesday = monday;
// etc.
yellow.push(monday);
yellow.push(tuesday);
// etc.
```

Next create a function that takes two parameters - day of week and hour - on the input and returns a rate for that hour. Inside the function, search through the non-default rates for day and hour corresponding the input parameters. If no non-default rate is found, return the default (white) rate.

Finally, create a function that has two input parameters from and to and loops time hour by hour and calls the previous function to get rate for every hour.